# No me llegan los correos de formulario aun cuando parece que si envia

Tags: php, formularios, web, servidor, hosting

Tengo un reseller con varios dominios en el, todo funcionaba bien, hasta hace 5 días que los correos dejaron de llegar a mi mail, todo funciona perfectamente, el sitio me manda a la pagina de agradecimiento que configure, pero el correo nunca llega a la cuenta de correo.

Les muestro mi archivo php:

```
<?

    require_once "recaptchalib.php";

        // Recepcion de datos
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $correo=$_POST['mail'];
        $telefono=$_POST['phone'];
        $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];
        $asunto='Página web de Starfix / Contacto';

         $secret = "xxxxxx";
        $response = null;
        // comprueba la clave secreta
        $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

        //Fin de recepcion de datos


        if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
            $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
            );
         }


     if ($response != null && $response->success) {
        // Si el código es correcto, seguimos procesando el formulario como siempre
        // Accion de envio
    //------------------//
    $para='xxxxxx@gmail.com';
    $mensaje='Mensaje de Starfix (Contacto):

    Nombre: '.$nombre.'

    Correo: '.$correo.'

    Teléfono: '.$telefono.'

    Mensaje: '.$mensaje.'

    ';

    $desde='From:StarFix.com <www.starfix.com.mx>';
     mail($para, $asunto,$mensaje, $desde);
    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: http://www.starfix.com.mx/gracias.html");

    exit;

      } else {
        // Si el código no es válido, lanzamos mensaje de error al usuario
         echo "Te Falto Seleccionar la casilla";
      }

      ?>
```

Comment: No te da ningun error ??? Al ejecutar o en los logs ?? De todas formas `mail($para, $asunto,$mensaje, $desde)` ahi te falta un **;** al final

Comment: @j0se el ; es porque habia estado haciendo mil pruebas y lo olvide, ya lo revise incluyendo la funcion mail() en una If y todo salio perfecto no muestra errores en niguna parte

Comment: Intenta ejecutarlo en tu localhost para ver si te funciona... a veces por enviar muchos correos (dependiendo del hosting de tu correo electrónico) te pueden considerar como un sospechoso de enviar spam y por eso pueden no llegar, pero de todos modos en el inbox de base de deberian dar algun error.

Comment: SI todo funcionaba hasta hace 5 días, puede ser que el problema esté en el hosting. Que se hallan cambiado los permisos de ejecucción de determinados comandos, o acciones, como por ejemplo el envío de emails. Pregunta al servicio técnico de tu hosting.

Comment: @Lukas en efecto, en el localhost funciona bien, creo que el problema es mas por el lado del hosting

Comment: Lo que dice Lukas tambien se puede comprobar si vas a tu carpeta de SPAM y mira si tienes algo alli.

Comment: @j0se si bueno como hay certificado SSL los correos no llegan a SPAM, igual revise la bandeja y nada

Comment: @BrunoGuevara si no me equivoco, tener o no tener certificado SSL en el servidor no va a influir en que llegue o no como spam. Importa más el contenido y la "reputación" del servidor que los envía. ¿Has probado a poner que se muestren todos los errores/warnings de la página y llamarla manualmente para ver si algo ocurre que hace que no se envíe correctamente?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro pues los correos funcionaban perfectos y llegaban a la bandeja, si se cancelaba el certificado SSL el correo inmediatamente llegaba a SPAM, de igual manera ya revise por todas partes y los correos no llegan a la cuenta

Comment: lo pudieron resolver? Porque me pasa lo mismo. Envio un formulario que es bastante largo, parece enviarlo lo más bien, pero no me llega al mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos Bruno, el problema es que redireccionas sin esperar a que `mail()` termine su proceso de envío. Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php

// Todo tu código

if ( mail( $destino, $asunto, $cuerpo, $cabecera ) ) {
    header("Location: $tu_web");
}

?>
```

De esa manera si la respuesta del `mail()` es true si redirecciona, sino no lo hará.... Nos cuentas que tal te fue